# ERROR: role "postgres" already exists while trying to restore RDS database inside a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, amazon-rds, psql, pg-restore

I am trying to dump RDS database with roles and following the commands as per their [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-manageddatabases.postgresql-rds-postgresql-full-load-pd_dump.html)

My dump commands look like this and works without any error
Globals dump

```
pg_dumpall \
    --globals-only \
    --no-password \
    --no-role-passwords \
    --encoding="${encoding}" \
    --file="${backup_dirname}/${globals_filename}" \
    --host="${host}" \
    --port="${port}" \
    --username="${username}"
```

Database dump

```
pg_dump \
    --blobs \
    --create \
    --no-password  \
    --dbname="${dbname}" \
    --encoding="${encoding}" \
    --file="${backup_dirname}/${dump_filename}" \
    --format="directory" \
    --host="${host}" \
    --jobs="${workers}" \
    --port="${port}" \
    --username="${username}"
```

My restore command looks like this

```
docker ps -aq --filter "name=${container_name}" | grep -q . && docker stop "${container_name}" && docker rm -fv "${container_name}"

docker run --detach --name "${container_name}" -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword postgres

until docker exec -it "${container_name}" psql -U postgres -c "SELECT 1 AS working"; do
    sleep 1
done

docker cp "globals.dump" "${container_name}:/home/globals.dump"

docker cp "pg_ch_api_db" "${container_name}:/home/pg_ch_api_db"

docker exec -it "${container_name}" sh -c "psql --no-password --quiet --host="${host}" --port="${port}" --username="${username}" --file=/home/globals.dump"
```

I basically downloaded the dump tar.gz file from S3, extracted it and copied it to my running postgresql docker container
It gives me the following errors

```
psql:/home/globals.dump:18: ERROR:  role "postgres" already exists
psql:/home/globals.dump:21: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:23: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:25: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:27: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:29: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:31: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:33: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:35: ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superuser roles or change superuser attribute
psql:/home/globals.dump:49: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_statement"
psql:/home/globals.dump:54: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_min_error_statement"
psql:/home/globals.dump:59: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_min_messages"
psql:/home/globals.dump:74: NOTICE:  permission will be denied to set role "rdsadmin"
psql:/home/globals.dump:79: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "auto_explain.log_min_duration"
psql:/home/globals.dump:84: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "temp_file_limit"
psql:/home/globals.dump:109: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "pg_hint_plan.enable_hint"
psql:/home/globals.dump:123: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_statement"
psql:/home/globals.dump:128: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_min_error_statement"
psql:/home/globals.dump:133: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "log_min_messages"
psql:/home/globals.dump:158: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "auto_explain.log_min_duration"
psql:/home/globals.dump:163: NOTICE:  permission will be denied to set role "rdstopmgr"
psql:/home/globals.dump:168: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "temp_file_limit"
psql:/home/globals.dump:173: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "pg_hint_plan.enable_hint"
psql:/home/globals.dump:190: ERROR:  must be superuser to set grantor
psql:/home/globals.dump:191: ERROR:  must be superuser to set grantor
psql:/home/globals.dump:192: ERROR:  must be superuser to set grantor
psql:/home/globals.dump:193: ERROR:  must be superuser to set grantor
psql:/home/globals.dump:194: ERROR:  must be superuser to set grantor
psql:/home/globals.dump:195: ERROR:  must be superuser to set grantor
psql:/home/globals.dump:202: ERROR:  permission denied to create tablespace "rds_temp_tablespace"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create a tablespace.
psql:/home/globals.dump:203: ERROR:  tablespace "rds_temp_tablespace" does not exist
```

I understand this is happening because the postgres role was present in the dump sql generated by pg_dumpall but how do I workaround this issue?

Comment: Is this a `docker` container (`image`) built by you, or is the official image. When `postgresql` starts, it starts as a regular user. What is your goal, to start a container from an existing backup, as a "restore" procedure ?

Comment: @azbarcea official postgres docker image
goal is to verify if the restore was properly done and the rows and tables exist in the database inside docker after restoring

Comment: That first error is probably just a nuisance error report which could be ignored.  The following "real" errors are probably unrelated to that first one.  What is $username set to during all of this?

Comment: @jjanes postgres postgres both dbname and username

Comment: The file from pg_dumpall must be replayed as a superuser, and apparently 'postgres' (or whatever $username is set to) is not a superuser on your container.  That is quite weird, but that is what it looks like.